# Наречие "слишком" в сочетании с прилагательным "вкусный"

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, стилистика, семантика, наречия

Есть предложение.

*Еда была **слишком** вкусной, поэтому я не мог перестать её есть.*

Как мне кажется, из-за наречия "слишком" нельзя сказать "я не мог перестать её есть", поскольку оно употребляется в основном с негативным оттенком.

Ср.: *Вы **слишком** много курите!* ◆ *Шкаф **слишком** высокий, может не пройти в дверь.

Вы **слишком** много говорите!*

P. S.

Просьба отвечать обоснованно.

Comment: На что 'отвечать обоснованно', на то, что вам кажется? Довольно нелогичная просьба: обоснованно опровергать мерещащееся.

Comment: Вот именно! Обосновать ответ на мой вопрос: корректно ли здесь наречие слишком. Неужели непонятно? Да, мне кажется, я не уверен. Поэтому мне нужен обоснованный ответ: опровергающий или подтверждающий мои сомнения.

Comment: Да но, в тексте упор делается не на вывод, а на процесс.

Comment: Слишком я любил на этом свете
Все, что душу облекает в плоть... (С. Есенин). Это тоже неправильно?  А как надо любить? Умеренно, в определенном количестве?

Comment: Вот в чем вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово "слишком" всегда имеет **негативный оттенок**, так как этимологически связано со словом слова **"лихо"** – зло, беда, несчастье. Хотя и в своей этимологии оно довольно противоречиво.

Все, что "слишком", нам не нравится – мы привыкли жить **в режиме ограниченности** (вероятно, в силу своей природы или просто привычки). Но это так, философия...

Что касается конкретного примера, то ему для ясности не хватает контекста: *Еда была **слишком** вкусной, поэтому я не мог перестать её есть, **хотя..**.*

Или: *Еда была **слишком** вкусной, **чтобы** я мог перестать её есть...*

А хотел ли наш герой **перестать есть?** Вероятно, да, если использует наречие "слишком".  Какой-то **негатив** в ситуации присутствовал: опасение за свое здоровье, уместность своего поведения или что-то другое.

"**Но вот обожрался ли он**" – это еще вопрос. Может, еще и не наелся даже...

Comment: А вообще это вопрос из теста по английскому. Надо было вставить слово слишком( too). Вот я и засомневался.

Answer (score 1):

"Слишком" — это всегда негативный оттенок, да, но почему? Потому, что означает чрезмерность (даже в случае восхищения: "Этот пианист слишком хорош для этого зала!"); и то, что человек потерял над собой контроль и обожрался из-за *слишком вкусной* еды, вряд ли можно назвать позитивной ситуацией. Поэтому наречие совершенно корректно.

Comment: Но вот обожрался ли...Вот в чем вопрос. По смыслу здесь вполне позитивный оттенок.